# WebSphere Java Security Issue :

Tags: websphere, war, java-security

5I haven't worked on Websphere earlier and now stuck with the Security Issue.

- I have deployed a War file in WebSphere. 
  Path : C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01\installedApps\ip-0AC30DDBNode01Cell\DMS_war.ear
- From UI, when we click on specific button it loads a JSP file, which in turn tries to read an xml file ( stored in WEB-INF/classes/mcc.xml).
- The jsp file is not able to READ the xml file.

Please help in how to add the security/permission WebSphere.
Also I'm not sure in which file we have to do this.( app.policy,java.policy,was.policy)

Log

> com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper service SRVE0068E: Uncaught exception created in one of the service methods of the servlet /awc/pcmgr/pcmgr.jsp in application DMS_war. **Exception created : java.security.AccessControlException: Access denied (java.io.FilePermission C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01\installedApps\ip-0AC30DDBNode01Cell\DMS_war.ear\DMS.war\WEB-INF\classes\mcc.xml read)**
>       at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:108)
>       at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:532)
>       at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkRead(SecurityManager.java:871)

So far I tried everything , heres the latest **was.policy** file. (location : META-INF/)

```
//
// Template policy file for enterprise application.
// Extra permissions can be added if required by the enterprise application.
//
// NOTE: Syntax errors in the policy files will cause the enterprise application FAIL to start.
//       Extreme care should be taken when editing these policy files. It is advised to use
//       the policytool provided by the JDK for editing the policy files
//       (WAS_HOME/java/jre/bin/policytool). 
//

grant codeBase "file:${application}" {
permission java.security.AllPermission;
};

grant codeBase "file:${jars}" {
};

grant codeBase "file:${connectorComponent}" {
};

grant codeBase "file:${webComponent}" {
};

grant codeBase "file:${ejbComponent}" {
};
```

**UPDATE** : 
This is how existing code reads XML file

```
SAXBuilder builder  = new SAXBuilder();
Document   doc      = builder.build(getServletContext().getRealPath("/WEB-INF/classes/mcc.xml")); 
// Use doc to get properties defined in file
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you try to disable Java 2 Security via admin console?

Comment: Yes, I tried that also. But same result. Isn't there some way to add permission for the asked resource(xml file in my case) in policy file ?

Comment: If you disabled Java 2 Security that exception should no longer appear. In general, your `was.policy` file, with just first entry should be ok. You can set `com.ibm.websphere.java2secman.norethrow` property to just log the missing permission. See [Java 2 security](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/csec_rsecmgr2.html?lang=en) for more details.

Comment: Actually what I really want is that jsp page should be able to READ the xml file. Does by setting this property will that be achievable ?

Comment: Yes, but then you in a sense disable whole Java 2 Security. So if it is not needed, just disable Java 2 security and restart the server, not create that property. If Java 2 Security is required, you can use that property to find out missing permission, but you shouldn't leave it on.

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier to judge it you post piece of your source code where you read the file. But if I were you I would try reading that file as a resource steam.

Something like this:

```
InputStream is = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("mcc.xml");
if (is == null) {
    // file not found or something went wrong
}

// read the stream
```

Comment: This looks like JDom. If yes, then approach with `getResourceAsStream(...)` should work for you. `SAXBuilder` has corresponding `build` method accepting an `InputStream`.

Comment: But I'm still confused why using SAXBuilder it is giving File Read Permission Error and this will not be there using getResourceAsStream(...) ? If possible can you explain in detail ?

Comment: Have you tried with `getResourceAsStream`?
It may behave differently because depending on how app is packaged\deployed (whether it is exploded dir or jar\war) and other factors.
I'm not sure it'll work, but i would try that.